# How to use client objects(like localstorage) in NextJS 14 server actions

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js14

According to NextJS docs, the best way to handle form submissions in NextJS 14 is by using server actions. I am trying to submit a signup form and create a user and set a JWT token in localstorage. However, I cannot get access to localstorage through server actions (as expected)

What is the workaround for it?

```js
export default function Client() {
  async function handleCreateAccount(formData) {
    'use server'
    // getting access to formData, as expected
    console.log(formData)

    // Understandably, localstorage is not accessible. But what is the workaround?
    localStorage.setItem('jwt', 1)
  }

  return (
      <form className="border p-6 rounded-md" action={handleCreateAccount}>
          <label htmlFor="email" className="block mt-2 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-600 uppercase">E-mail</label>
          <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" autoComplete="email" required
            className="block w-full p-2 mt-2 text-gray-800 transition-all border-b border-gray-200 focus:text-gray-500 outline-none focus:border-gray-400" />
      </form>
  )
}
```

Before anything, my initial approach was a standard method of trying to call handleCreateAccount and trying to send a fetch request to /api/signup to the POST() function in /api/signup/route.js and work with the response but NextJS gave an error stating that server actions are not accessible without 'use server' directive. If so, how do I write client-side JS functions?

An easy method to submit a POST form and get token stored into localstorage from response would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set localStorage only on the client. Let ServerActions return to the client what you need, access the information on the client and do whatever you need to do.

https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/hooks/useFormState